# Proving that XOR and AND are or aren't expressively complete

Tags: logic, modular-arithmetic

## Background

I read that AND and XOR can be thought of modulo 2 multiplication and modulo 2 addition, respectively.

Thus, it seemed reasonable that XOR and AND could be expressively complete, since it seems you can do a lot in math with just the ability to add and multiply. After a while trying to find a proof, I can't seem to do it.

## Work so far:

I have been able to prove that {XOR, AND, t} is expressively complete, where t is a tautological statement. I've tried to come up with a tautology using XOR and AND but to no avail. Getting a contradictory statement was easy, that won't help unless I can define an expression which is equal to NOT, which I haven't found.

## Conclusion/TLDR

I can't find a proof for {XOR, AND} being expressively complete, but I don't know how to prove that a set is not expressively complete. I'd appreciate some guidance in working out this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any expression built up using just XOR and AND; plug in "False" for all the variables, and you'll always get a result of "False".  That's because $$\text{False AND False = False}$$ and $$\text{False XOR False = False.}$$

So XOR and AND together aren't functionally complete.  (For instance, you can't get negation, or any other operation where the row of the truth table with all F's as input has a T as output.)